# Calcuating the shooting angle of bullet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

> A bullet is firing as the horizontal range will be $3$ times of its height.

So I want to calcuate the shooting angle of bullet.

**My Question:** Should I use this formula?

> $x_{range} = v t$
>
> $h=\frac{1}{2} g t^2$
>
> $v_x = v_0$
>
> $v_y = gt$
>
> $v_y^2 = 2gh$
>
> $v^2 = v_0^2 + v_y^2$

If I'm wrong please let me know about what formula i ought to use.

Comment: Did i ask it wrong?

Comment: Can you be a bit clear on the symbols?

Comment: @SayanMandal Oh, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: You can see the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to solve it with your equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the velocity with which it is shot is $v$, and the angle be $\theta$. Then, the horizontal range is
$$R=v\cos\theta\,t$$
where $t$ is the time taken to complete the motion. The maximum height $H$ can be found from,
$$v^2\sin^2\theta=2gH$$
Also, at time $t/2$, the vertical velocity becomes $0$. So,
$$v\sin\theta=g\frac{t}{2}$$
Now, $R=3H$. And then you can solve these equations to eliminate $v$ and $t$ to get $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $\frac{x}{y} =3$

You also know that 
$x=\frac{v_0^2sen^2\theta}{2g}$
$y=\frac{v_0^2sen2\theta}{g}$

Easily follows 
$\frac{x}{y}=tan\theta=3$

$\theta=arctan 3$

Comment: Let me try to solve it again with yours now. Thanks!